# FatFree how to route restfull calls?

Tags: routes, fat-free-framework

I am trying to set up a restful api application based on fatfree

Directory tree:

```
├── config.ini  
├── index.php  
├── lib  
├── operator  
│   ├── logs  
│   ├── models  
│   └── resources  
│         └── Employee.php  
└── ui
```

config.ini:

```
[globals]
DEBUG=3
UI=ui/
AUTOLOAD=operator/resources
```

index.php:

```
<?php
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->config('config.ini');

//$f3->map('/employee/','operator/resources/Employee'); 

$f3->route('GET /employee','opertaor\resource\Employee->get'); 

$f3->run();
```

I prefer using map but it also not working. ???

Can I use $f3->route('GET /employee','Employee->get'); because Employee is autoloaded?

Employee.php:

```
<?php   
class Employee{
    function get() {echo View::instance()->render('welcome.htm');}
    function post() {}
    function put() {}
    function delete() {}
}
```

Error:

```
var/www/kinder/lib/base.php:1141 Base->call('operato/resources/Employee->get'
....
.... 
var/www/kinder/index.php:10 Base->run()
```

Comment: The stack trace you posted in this case isn't really helpful. Either you post the full stack trace, or the line above it, because it's indicates the "real" error. Beside that, you don't have to set a route to the get-function, because it's included in the `map()` you already did.

Comment: i guess you are using the wrong slashes... it has to be $f3->map('/employee/','operator\resources\Employee'); and Employee should be in a operator\resources namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Well it was the wrong slashes but the AUTOLOAD slashes.
Autoload path should end with slash.
After that you can refer the class without the path.

AUTOLOAD=operator/resources/
$f3->map('/employee','Employee');

Thank you